# What governs the size of a recordset returned from a SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

What are the determining factors as to the size of a record set, or the number of records that can be returned from an open cursor, from a query? Is there any limit?

```
Select * from table; //How many results can be retrieved max?
Select * from table limit 0, 999999; //how many max number I can give here?
```

I am working in struts json. Actually I want to use the json result for two purposes.

1. Render a grid(dataTables) with pagination where limit should be applied according to the input.
2. Export the result to excel where there should be any limit applied. But I still want to use the same request url. I came up with an idea to pass the limit to a maximum possible number to request all the data from the table to return in the excel.

Comment: I think that there is no limit. If the data is very large you'll have to wait for a while.

Comment: [MySQL Limits](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/limits.html). But as always, the advice to give for a question like this is "if you have to ask, you're doing something wrong". E.g. do you have any user interface or mechanism in which it is sensible to actually place a million results? How would someone *use* such an interface in a meaningful way?

Comment: Thanks  octopusgrabbus. I just asked to reuse a query like **select * from table limit ?**. I want to pass maximum possible limit here.

Comment: You need to ask a more specific question. I've edited it to make the question more palatable, but still don't know why you're asking the question. I suggest you edit the question and provide programming environment, OS, tools, and so on what something about your table, its use (how many applications read it and how often), and so on.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the question describing the environment where i need such queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to read the MySQL documentation, particularly [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-count-limit.html).

Comment: Thanks. I read the document. I understood that the limit is not depending upon number of records. But it depends on total size of records (or there is a limit only for row - as per documentation?). Correct me if am wrong.

Comment: There appears to be a row size limit of 65,535 bytes, excluding BLOBS.  Blobs tend to be stored differently to other data, so I would have thought that the maximum row size for your rows will be something along the lines of `(65535 - (count_of_blobs * blob_header_size))`.